# How to iterate over Unicode in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode-string

I need to iterate over possible Unicode in a standard WinForms textbox. For instance, a file containing this word:

```
“likable”
```

when viewed in a hex viewer (like XVI32) is:

[image]

However, when this is in a textbox and I attempt to access the bytes one at a time, instead of the first byte being 0xE2, I get 0x1C.

As the textboxes support a variety of encodings I would like to do so as well, but that doesn't seem to be working.

For starters I would like to create a byte[] array, store these bytes into that array and write them out (and go on from there).

I would like the code to be encoding-agnostic, if that's possible.

I figured it out. The " sign is 0x201C, so that explains it all.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are looking for. The content of the file is byte array, while the `Text` property of `TextBox` is a Unicode string.

Comment: I am aware of that. But can I treat a unicode string as a byte array? When I'm getting at is that they are just a stream of bytes (I assume). How do I access them?

Comment: [Encoding.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: The file above is 13 bytes long. The first byte is 0xE2. But no matter it seems, how I access it the first byte is 0x1C and the second is 0x20. How do I access this data so byte 0 is 0xE2 and byte1 is 0x80?

Comment: [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllBytes_System_String_)

Comment: The file was just an example. This is from a text box. To me this should be very simple: how to access the values in a text box as bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the bytes of the string correctly, you just can't ignore encoding with a string.

Your example file is encoded in UTF-8, so [“](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C) is the 3 bytes `0xE2 0x80 0x9C`.  The string in your `TextBox` will be a [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) which is encoded in UTF-16, so [“](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C) which uses as the 16 bit word `0x201C`.  On x86, words are stored [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian), so it will be stored in memory as `0x1C 0x20`.  Which is exactly what you are seeing.

When reading the bytes from the string in the `TextBox` (or any string), it will always be UTF-16 in .Net.  When reading the file from disk (or copying it from the clipboard) .Net will convert the UTF-8 bytes to UTF-16 `System.String`.

If you want to access the bytes of a `System.String` as UTF-8 bytes, use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.